# OnBase Unity Editor and Visual Stuidio

Tags: visual-studio, c#, document-management, integration

I started a new job which requires me to write some c# scripts for OnBase.
[OnBase](https://www.onbase.com/en/product/onbase-platform)

is an enterprise document management tool. OnBase has a development tool called OnBase Studio which is utilized to build workflows for documents. OnBase studio provides some additional functionality such as writing c# code to enhance functionality.

**Problem:**

Using OnBase Studio's inbuilt code editor to write c# code is not a pleasant experience as the editor lacks a lot of essential functionalities such as creating breakpoints, step by step debugging etc. I was wondering if anyone has successfully integrated visual studio or visual studio code for the purposes of code debugging and writing code? I went through the OnBase documentation to see if there is anyway i can do this but i couldn't find anything helpful.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser! Your question is a development question so it might fit better in StackOverflow. https://stackoverflow.com/

Comment: If the code is just C# then you can use whatever you want to edit it. Debugging might prove more difficult because of the external dependencies. I would say, "just do it". Try it out and come back when you get stuck.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I settled on is starting all my scripts in VisualStudio in a single solution, using intellisense, Resharper, git, and whatever else you need, then when ready, copy/pasting the source to OnBase studio for final testing.  There is a mechanism for deploying from VS straight to OnBase via Web Service Publishing (WSP), but I found the benefits weren't really worth the lift to configure it.